# Touchpad lagging in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, mouse, touchpad, cursor

I have Dell Inspiron 15 and I didn't update or install anything recently but I started having trouble with my touchpad since yesterday. When I start the system, the cursor doesn't appear at all or if it appears, it lags a lot so I suspend the laptop and after activating it again, the mouse works fine but only for a few minutes after which it starts lagging.
I already tried enabling and disabling the touchpad through xinput, echo on | sudo tee command and also reinstalled xorg (though I'm not sure if was remotely even related with the problem) but as you can tell, I have no idea what I'm doing.
Help would be appreciated!